# how to detect the facial profile (side face)?

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection

I've been using **Opencv with python** for face detection and it works. My question is, whether the front and side faces (facial profile) can be detected simultaneously (at one time in one program)? Can anyone give me a hint to detect front and side profile of a face at the same time ?
Thank you.

Comment: you have to run another loop inside the loop where you detect the front profile. Just call the Haarcascade data inside the Loop. It will work

Comment: or you can run Two loop separately, one for front profile and another for side. All you need is the data set

Comment: @myCode ok i'll try it